# Ubicar un salto de linea en una lista

Tags: java, jframe

una duda: ¿cómo puedo ubicar un salto de linea en una lista en un solo visualizar? Estoy haciendo método de encapsulamiento?

```
 public DefaultListModel visualizar ()
 {
    DefaultListModel modeloLista= new DefaultListModel();  

    modelo copiaRegistro=registro;

    while (copiaRegistro !=null)
    {
        modeloLista.addElement(copiaRegistro.getCedula()+ " " + 

       copiaRegistro.getNombre()+ " " + copiaRegistro.getEdad());

       copiaRegistro=copiaRegistro.getSiguiente();

    }
    return modeloLista;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más explicit@?

Comment: YemisiSCG, lo que trato de decir es que al momento de visualizar en la lista las cosas se ven de este modo

Comment: Su cédula es:131 Su nombre es:Zirick Su edad:18 y yo quiero que se me vea

Comment: Saltando de línea osea al momento de poner la cedula que me realice un salto y luego que se vea el nombre y así sucesivamente el \n no me ha funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Supongo es para un JList de swing y quiere algo similar a esto:
[image: JList]

De igual manera el \ln no funciona asi como tampoco funciona en un JLabel, para estos casos es recomendable usar codigo HTML:

```html
<html><body>Su cédula es:131<br>Su nombre es:Zirick<br>Su edad:18</body></html>
```

esto introducirlo como String

```
"<html><body>Su cédula es:"+CED+"<br>Su nombre es:"+NOM+"<br>Su edad:"+EDAD+"</body></html>"
```

Saludos y espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: me puedes ayudar donde colocar ese pedaso de codigo?

Comment: Dentro de tu while, cuando agregas elementos a modeloLista,  **modeloLista.addElement("<html><body>Su cédula es:"+copiaRegistro.getCedula()+"<br>Su nombre es:"+copiaRegistro.getNombre()+"<br>Su edad:"+copiaRegistro.getEdad()+"</body></html>")**, Si esta usando una JList?